# XML schema validation : Check the excistance of special characters

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I want to validate my XML file using XSD schema. In there, I want to check whether a specific attribute value contains some character (eg: $ character). How can I check this with my XSD. My XML is look like this.

```
<parent name="abc">
..........
..........
</parent>

<parent name="ef$">
........
........
</parent>
```

I want to check the excistance of "$" character inside the attribute value and parse an error. Could you suggest me a XSD schema for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this you want your [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256143%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to have a specific datatype. So you aren't *checking* what the value is, more *declaring* what it can be.

Here, we define a restricted datatype based on a string. Here, the [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256481%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the xs:pattern is `[^$]*` which translates to "0 or more characters that *aren't* a '$'":

```
<xs:simpleType name="myAttribute">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[^$]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then, on the declaration of the `parent` element, the attribute has that restricted datatype.

```
<xs:element name="parent">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="myAttribute"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```